# nodejs child_process scope issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I am using child_process(fork) of nodejs then I send data to a particular file and receive data but not console that data after receiving of process execution

first.js

> var cp = require('child_process');
> var child = cp.fork('./s/abc.js');
> child.send({data:'this come from parent process'});
> var x ;

> child.on('message', function(m) {
> console.log(m);   // output:- this come from child process
> x = m;
> });
> console.log(m);
> console.log(x);

abc.js (./s/abc.js)

> process.send({data:'this come from child process'});
> var x ;

> process.on('message', function(m) {
> console.log(m);   // output:- this come from parent process
> });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use function to console value after scope end

first.js

> var cp = require('child_process');
> var child = cp.fork('./s/abc.js');
> child.send({data:'this come from parent process'});
> var x ;

> child.on('message', function(m) {
> console.log(m);   // output:- this come from child process
> callTempFun(m);
> });
> function callTempFun(m){
> console.log(m);      // output:- this come from child process
> }

abc.js (./s/abc.js)

> process.send({data:'this come from child process'});
> var x ;

> process.on('message', function(m) {
> console.log(m);   // output:- this come from parent process
> });